# SBT can't find and import cats-core

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-cats

I'm starting a new project to try out Scala Cats, and my SBT seems to refuse to find the cats-core. It has no trouble bringing in something like ScalaTest, but whenever I try to refresh my sbt project with the cats-core as a `libraryDependencies`, it claims it is an unresolved dependency, looking into the error, it says:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.typelevel#cats-core_2.13;2.0.0-M2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/org.typelevel/cats-core_2.13/2.0.0-M2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/cats-core_2.13/2.0.0-M2/cats-core_2.13-2.0.0-M2.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.sbt/preloaded/org.typelevel/cats-core_2.13/2.0.0-M2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/me/.sbt/preloaded/org/typelevel/cats-core_2.13/2.0.0-M2/cats-core_2.13-2.0.0-M2.pom
[warn] ==== cats-core: tried
[warn]   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core/org/typelevel/cats-core_2.13/2.0.0-M2/cats-core_2.13-2.0.0-M2.pom
```

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.0.0-M2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
)

resolvers += "cats-core" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core" // it gives the same errors without this line

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xfatal-warnings","-Ypartial-unification")

val exportFullResolvers = taskKey[Unit]("debug resolvers")

exportFullResolvers := {
  for {
    (resolver,idx) <- fullResolvers.value.zipWithIndex
  } println(s"${idx}.  ${resolver.name}")
}
```

Any idea how to bring it in?

Comment: You need to use **Cats** `2.0.0-M4` for **Scala** `2.13.0`. - you can check the version compability [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core).

Comment: It would be nice if sbt could tell you that similar artifacts are available at a certain repo, so at least know you're in the neighborhood.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that did the trick. If you supply that as an answer, I'll be happy to give you the checkmark.

Comment: [Cats `2.0.0-RC1`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v2.0.0-RC1) has been released.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty explicit `module not found: org.typelevel#cats-core_2.13;2.0.0-M2`

What I do is then just search (google) for `mavenrepo cats-core`

Usually the top result will lead you to

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core

Or on on (sometimes this site is easier, when navigating scala versions):

https://index.scala-lang.org/typelevel/cats/cats-core

Comment: Looking for stuff in mvnrepository is always a great start, and I think SBT should know to look there in the first place (it does, I think), but it wouldn't bring that in - turns out it was a version discrepancy.

Comment: @NateH06 that's the idea of this answer - sbt tries to resolve whatever you define - if it cannot resolve it it fails. So you have a way to figure out the correct version. mvnrepository just shows available mavenrepos and its content (where sbt looks for)

Comment: That makes sense now, I didn't catch that's what you were angling at. Without knowing that the import was failing due to language version incompatibility, I want sure what to do with your suggestion. Thanks!